# Kendo Angular Parse month number to month name

Tags: angular, date, kendo-ui, grid, kendo-ui-angular2

how can i display month names without converting each month number via a function

this is my kendo grid with month column:

```
<kendo-grid-column field="month">
        <ng-template kendoGridCellTemplate let-dataItem="dataItem">
                <span>{{convertMonthNToName(dataItem)}}</span>
        </ng-template>
</kendo-grid-column>
```

the function convertMonthNToName contains a switch that returns a string month name

Is there anything kendo preset that does this? via a parse or via culture libraries

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If perceived well, please use [DatePipe](https://angular.io/api/common/DatePipe) and try the following:

```
<kendo-grid-column field="month">
     <ng-template kendoGridCellTemplate let-dataItem="dataItem">
             <span>{{dataItem | date: 'MMMM'}}</span>
     </ng-template>
</kendo-grid-column>
```

Please provide some stackblitz demo to make it more specific.